# Dynamically change a return value of a library in Java

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Is it possible to dynamically (while debugging) change a return value of a library method.

```
public String libraryMethod throws LibraryException() {
   #When I enter here while debugging
   # I want to return a different value from 
   # what library is going to return
   # or throw an exception which library might have thrown
   # under different circumstances
   ...
}
```

I am using Intellij IDEA as ide, if that helps.

Is it possible all(or any) of this without editing library's source code

Comment: Use a mocking framework.

Comment: Step by step debug, or running in debug mode?

Answer (score 0):

If you assign the result from the library call to a local variable prior to returning from the method, and you set a breakpoint prior to the return call, you can modify the value of the local variable in IntelliJ prior to returning from the method.

I think you just right click on the variable in the debugger and then set the value of whatever is assign to the variable.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not assigned to a local variable